# Makefile; gcc not working? Believe Mavericks is responsible

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, makefile, osx-mavericks

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute my make file:

`clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

The issue occurred when I upgraded to Mac OSX Mavericks (Xcode 5.0.1). I have spent days trying to figure this problem out on the forums, and I'm just very lost. After deleting a previous XCode version, I reinstalled a clean one (from the Mac App Store). When I ran the following:

`sudo port install gcc49`

It froze trying to build `libgcc-devel`.

Any help as I'm desperate, working on dissertation work.

Comment: readPVCData: readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h
 gcc -o readPVCData readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h -lm -lsndfile

readPVCData.o: readPVCData.c readlib.h
 gcc -c readPVCData.c

readfunc.o: readfunc.c readlib.h
 gcc -c readfunc.c

Comment: Edit it into the post with proper formatting please.

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is the readlib.h in `gcc -o readPVCData readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h -lm -lsndfile`. Take it out.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the n00b question. Best

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

When the OP wrote:

> `readPVCData: readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h 
>           gcc -o readPVCData readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h -lm -lsndfile
>   readPVCData.o: readPVCData.c readlib.h 
>           gcc -c readPVCData.c 
>   readfunc.o: readfunc.c readlib.h 
>           gcc -c readfunc.c`

@Kevin wrote:

> Pretty sure your problem is the `readlib.h` in `gcc -o readPVCData readPVCData.o readfunc.o readlib.h -lm -lsndfile`. Take it out.