# OSX Mavericks causes "cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files"

Tags: c, macos, gcc, makefile

Since I installed mavericks on my mac, I can't compile some of my programs.

**clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
**

The makefile is :

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -funroll-all-loops
EXEC = program
SRC = $(EXEC).c file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
LIB = $(SRC:.c=.h)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJ) $(LIB)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) -lm

%.o: %.c $(LIB)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

- gcc is redirected to clang, but I don't know if this causes the described error.
- gcc is installed
- I don't know how to cancel this redirection to test again.
- I saw this post : [Makefile; gcc not working? Believe Mavericks is responsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748656/makefile-gcc-not-working-believe-mavericks-is-responsible) but I don't really understand the problem and its resolution

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Could you include the full output of `make` instead of just the error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would but I can't (because of the confidentiality of this work in my company).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove `$(LIB)` from the line:

```
$(EXEC): $(OBJ) $(LIB)
```

The way `LIB` is defined, it has the value `program.h file1.h file2.h file3.h file4.h`. This has two effects.

First, it says that `$(EXEC)`, which is `program`, depends on the `.h` files. However, `program` depends directly only on the `.o` files. `program` does not directly use the `.h` files in its build, so the dependencies for `program` should not include the `.h` files.

Second, the `$^` in the command says to list all the files that the target depends on. This passes all the `.o` and `.h` files to the compiler. When the compiler sees several `.h` files listed, it figures that several source files will be compiled, and therefore several object files will be produced.

When you remove `$(LIB)` from the dependencies in this rule, the `.h` files will not be listed in the command. Then the compiler will see only several `.o` files, so it will know it is linking several objects into one executable and will not attempt to compile source files.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your detailed explanation (and your wasted time!). However, I did it and I get new errors I did not have before Maverick (about some internal linkage). I'm trying to solve them ;-)